# Modificar stock de productos cuando un producto sea comprado - React.js

Tags: reactjs

estoy por terminar mi primera [app](https://husdady.github.io/simulador-de-compras/) hecha con React, y necesito que tenga una ultima funcionalidad pero es algo tedioso de hacer. Cada vez que se compre un producto, el stock debe reducirse dependiendo del numero de productos comprados.

Ejm: Compras 2 Samsung Galaxy A20, el stock total de este es 4, entonces al realizarse una compra su stock ya no seria 4 sino 2, y este numero deberia ser igual cada vez que se haga cualquier filtro, ya sea por orden, precio, busqueda, o categoria.

Ya que por alguna razon en el [json](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras/blob/main/json/celulares.json) donde imprimo la informacion de los celulares, el stock siempre va seguir siendo el mismo cuando se realiza un filtro. El sgte componente renderiza todos los celulares:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/product.css';

class Product extends Component{

  render(){
    const { id, imagen, modelo, precio, stock } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="product" key={id} data-product={id}>
        <figure>
          <img loading="lazy" src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${imagen}`} alt={modelo} title={modelo} />
        </figure>
        <h3>{modelo}</h3>
        <h4>$/. {precio}</h4>

        <div className="quantity">
          <button className="increase"></button>
          
          <div className="count">{stock}</div>
          
          <button className="decrease"></button>
        </div>

        <button className="add-to-cart">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;Añadir al carrito</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Product;
```

Desde la propiedad `stock` muestro el stock de todos los productos, desde el sgte componente renderizo el anterior:

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Product from './Product';
import celulares from '../../json/celulares';

class App extends Component{

  state = {
    allProducts: celulares
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <section className="products">  
          {this.state.allProducts.length > 0 ? (this.state.allProducts.map( (x, index) => (
              <Product
              key={index}
              id={x.id}
              imagen={x.imagen}
              modelo={x.modelo}
              stock={x.stock}
              precio={x.precio}
              />
              )
            ))
            : null
          }
          </section>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

He cortado el componente para ir directo al grano y para que sea más fácil de leer, entonces si ya le defino una propiedad stock al componente , como puedo cambiar y mantener esa propiedad cada vez que un producto sea comprado?, como menciono arriba, cuando se realice algun filtro, debe seguir manteniendo el stock modificado. Es un problema algo tedioso, como se puede resolver esto? Gracias! . Desde este [link](https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras) puede ver los Componentes, están actualizados.

Comment: En que parte estas realizando la operación de descuento?

Comment: ¿Estás almacenando el stock en un estado que se actualice cada vez que alguien haga una compra?

Comment: Por alguna razon, no se habia actualizado los archivos en el github, desde aqui hago la operacion de compra: https://github.com/Husdady/simulador-de-compras/blob/main/components/header/ShoppingCart.js , desde la linea 22 hasta la 46, realizo el evento click en el boton comprar

Comment: Lo intente, pero vuelve al estado original cuando se hace realiza un filtro

Comment: Claro, vuelve a su estado inicial porque al momento de renderizar los celulares, estas usando tu archivo json no? Lo que deberías hacer es, o bien ir modificando los datos de ese archivo después de realizar la compra, o guardar la información en algun motor de BD, no se si me explique bien @Husdady

Comment: Aun no se base de datos, es lo proximo q deseo aprender, pero acerca de modificar los datos del json, a que te refieres, usando estados o modificar directo al json?

Comment: Modificar directamente el archivo, ya que estas leyendo los datos desde el archivo.

Comment: He buscado informacion, pero no logro encontrar algo solido para poder editar directo los datos del json, ¿podrias mostrarme un ejemplo claro de como se hace?

Comment: Paulo, pude resolver el problema. Muchas gracias por haberme ayudado con los problemas anterior, te deseo mucho éxito y bendiciones.

Comment: Bien! Recuerda incluir tu respuesta para futuros problemas similares @Husdady, mucho éxito. Que estés aprendiendo desarrollo por tu cuenta es un gran mérito, la comunidad siempre estará aquí para ayudarte!